# Попытка собрать из исходников qt 5.15 ("nmake" не является внутренней или внешней командой)

Tags: qt, visual-c++

собирал таким методом собрался только куте без куте креатора.

> Скачиваем архив исходников Qt для Windows
> (qt-everywhere-src-5.12.2.zip) с официального сайта.
> 2. Скачиваем утилиту jom и распаковываем её в каталог «C:\Qt\jom».
>
> 3. Создаем каталог, например, c:\Qt\Qt5.15.2-x64-msvc2019-static\5.15\Src и распаковываем в него
>    содержимое архива исходников. Сборка в дальнейшем будет привязана к
>    данному каталогу и букве диска. Каталог
>    qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.15.2 не создаем, т.е. получим
>    подкаталоги 5.15\Src\qtbase, 5.15\Src\coin и т.д.). msvc2019 – это
>    выбранный компилятор.
> 4. Редактируем файл msvc-desktop.conf (находится в каталоге c:\Qt\Qt5.15.2-x64-msvc2019-static\5.15\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\common):
>
> нужно заменить в переменных QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE,
> QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO и QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG значения -MD
> на -MT (для release), и -MDd на -MTd (для debug).
>
> 5. Запускаем командную строку (cmd) с правами администратора и последовательно выполняем в ней следующие команды:
>
> cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build" vcvarsall.bat amd64 set
> QTDIR=c:\Qt\Qt5.15.2-x64-msvc2019-static\5.15\Src\qtbase set
> PATH=c:\Qt\Qt5.15.2-x64-msvc2019-static\5.15\Src\qtbase\bin;%PATH% cd
> c:\Qt\Qt5.15.2-x64-msvc2019-static\5.15\Src\qtbase configure
> -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2019 -opengl desktop -static -nomake examples C:\Qt\jom\jom.exe -j 50 Аналогично
> делается для Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, 2013, 2015, 2017.

вот таким медотом сделал, собрался у меня 500 мегабайт куте но без куте креатора и т.д.
решил удалить и собрать из всей папки . чтоб всё было

```
F:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.15.10>configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2019 -opengl desktop -static -make examples -make tests -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -qt-pcre -qt-harfbuzz
+ cd qtbase
+ F:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.15.10\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2019 -opengl desktop -static -make examples -make tests -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -qt-pcre -qt-harfbuzz

Notice: re-mapping requested qmake spec to unified 'win32-msvc'.

Bootstrapping qmake ...
"nmake" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.



F:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.15.10>configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2019 -opengl desktop -static -make examples -make tests -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -qt-pcre -qt-harfbuzz C:\Qt\jom.exe -j 50
+ cd qtbase
+ F:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-5.15.10\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2019 -opengl desktop -static -make examples -make tests -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -qt-pcre -qt-harfbuzz C:\Qt\jom.exe -j 50

Notice: re-mapping requested qmake spec to unified 'win32-msvc'.

Bootstrapping qmake ...
"nmake" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Comment: `nmake не является внутренней или внешней командой`. Запустите это из Visual Studio command prompt, он знает, что такое `nmake`.

Comment: или сделайте bat-файл в котором первой строкой будет: `call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build"\vcvars32.bat` или соответствующией версии VS